# Unable to retrieve JSON, instead kept retrieving HTML

Tags: r, httr

I am passing the following arguments to retrieve the response in JSON format.

```
url <- "https://www.ted.com/conversation_forums/107?page=150&per_page=10&sort=newest"
resp<- httr::GET(url, add_headers('accept' = 'application/json'))
```

However, it kept returning the response in HTML format. I also tried using httr::content_type_json(), but same thing. Below is a snippet of the output:

```
Response [https://www.ted.com/conversation_forums/107?page=150&per_page=10&sort=newest]
  Date: 2020-03-13 02:01
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
  Size: 42.2 kB
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <html class="no-js loggedout oldie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js loggedout oldie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class='no-js loggedout' lang='en'><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<script>
  (function (H){
  H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js');
  if (('; '+document.cookie).match(/; _ted_user_id=/)) H.className=H.className.replace(/\bloggedou...
```

I checked that it is supposed to return JSON, so I am not really sure what happen here...Any pointers would be much appreciated! Thank you.

[image]

Comment: The link returns nothing for me. What are you trying to get? It seems you wanted to get some thread?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying. Yes, I was trying to get the discussion thread, but no worries, manage to solve it. After playing around, I realised that need to call using url with the following format instead: "https://www.ted.com/conversation_forums/107.json?page=150&per_page=10".